# Optimizing Equation involving CDF and PDF

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, optimization, bayesian-optimization

Assume you have two random variables, $v_b \sim N(\mu_b,\sigma_b^2)$ and $v_s \sim N(\mu_s,\sigma_s^2)$ and let $\rho$ be the correlation between them. Denote by $F$ and $f$ the CDF and PDF of the variables respectively, and assume I have the following optimization problem: $$\max_{\pi}F_{v_s}(\pi)(\mu_b-\pi)-\rho\sigma_b\sigma_sf_{v_s}(\pi)$$ where $\pi$ is the variable of interest. I am stuck on the approach - first, the second order conditions are of ambiguous sign. I'm also not convinced there exists a closed-form expression for $\pi$ after trying for several hours to solve it. How would I go about approximating solutions numerically? Can this even be done?

Comment: I would ask this question as: Consider a random variable $Y \sim N(\nu,\tau^2)$ with CDF $F$ and PDF $f$. Let $\mu$ and $c$ be other real numbers, which can be thought of as the mean of another normal variable $X$, and its covariance with $Y$. How can one maximize
$$\max_z[(\mu-z)F(z)-c f(z)]?$$There are indeed no closed-form solutions, but from this presentation it should be easier to apply standard numerical techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If getting more familiar with the (numeric rather than exact) solutions is the objective, then looking at some dynamic graphics would be helpful.  This can certainly be done in *R* and *Mathematica* (and probably several other languages).  Consider the following *Mathematica* code for looking at where the maximum occurs and the shape of the function being maximized:

```
Manipulate[sol = Quiet[FindMaximum[g[zz, \[Mu]b, \[Sigma]b, \[Mu]s, \[Sigma]s, \[Rho]], {{zz, zz0}}]];
 Show[Plot[g[z, \[Mu]b, \[Sigma]b, \[Mu]s, \[Sigma]s, \[Rho]], {z, -10, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "z = " <> ToString[zz /. sol[[2]]] <> ", Max = " <>   ToString[sol[[1]]]],
  ListPlot[{{zz /. sol[[2]], 0}, {zz /. sol[[2]], sol[[1]]}}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]],
 {{\[Mu]b, 7}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{\[Sigma]b, 6}, 0.001, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{\[Mu]s, 0}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{\[Sigma]s, 1}, 0.001, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{\[Rho], 0}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{zz0, 0, "Starting value"}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {\[Mu]b, \[Sigma]b, \[Mu]s, \[Sigma]s, \[Rho], zz0},
 Initialization :> (g[z_?NumericQ, \[Mu]b_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]b_?NumericQ, \[Mu]s_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]s_?NumericQ, \[Rho]_?NumericQ] := 
    CDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu]s, \[Sigma]s], z] (\[Mu]b - z) - \[Rho] \[Sigma]b \[Sigma]s PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu]s, \[Sigma]s], z])]
```

[image: Display of function and maximum]

Comment: Thank you, this is amazing